# I want to trigger buttons on a touch sensitive control panel (not a touchscreen)

Tags: arduino, touch-panel, thermostat

I have this cheap hot tub with an electronic controller with touch-sensitive buttons (not resistive since they work with no pressure, only a light touch). The panel is plastic and the buttons are marked with printed circles, and are illuminated from behind (see photo).

I'd like to be able to turn the power on and off remotely but I'm not sure how to trigger the buttons without a finger. Does anyone have any thoughts or suggestions on how I might be able to actuate the buttons? I tried taping a piece of aluminum foil connected to a wire over one of the buttons, but I couldn't reliably trigger it by touching the other end of the wire.

[image: The touch panel for the hot tub]

Comment: personally, i'd just go for the wiring and replicate electrical signals there instead of at the buttons.  try different materials at different rates of approach.  the change rather than the presence may be what is important.  should be able to motorize whatever works.

Comment: press the buttons with a plastic object to confirm that the buttons are not mechanical

Comment: I considered going for the wiring but I don't feel qualified, especially considering they're not standard switches. I'm learning that this is a lot more difficult than I thought :)

Comment: @jsotola can confirm that it's not mechanical.

Answer (score 2):

Once you figure out how to make the switch operate electrically, you can often synthesize that with Quad Analog switches or with R or C or just jumpers.

That assumes the analog voltages suitable with your logic levels. There are many other choices including 74HCTxxx.

Then your interface can be serial to parallel or parallel or I2C and filtered/shielded STP for noise immunity.

If not sure , try a small C like 1nF or a small R like 1k across switch
contacts and change to confirm sensitivity.